# presentable vs inductive categories

Tags: category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal, and let $D$ be a small $\infty$-category which admits $\kappa$-small colimits. Then is the canonical map $D \to Ind_\kappa(D)$ an equivalence, and if not why not? I ask because  Lurie's Higher Topos Theory Theorem 5.5.5.1 gives equivalent conditions to be a presentable $\infty$-category, and condition (4) seems to suggest to me that $D$ and $Ind_\kappa(D)$ are not equivalent (but Lurie does not say that). But I would have guessed they are equivalent since the $D$ has all $\kappa$-small colimits, and in particular it has all $\kappa$-filtered colimits, and so the identity map $D \to D$ factors as $D \to Ind(D) \to D$ by the universal property of inductive categories.

Also, I think my confusion has nothing to specific with $\infty$-categories; if you know the answer in the case of ordinary categories that is enough for me to believe.

Comment: You seem to be confused. $\kappa$-filtered diagrams are not necessarily $\kappa$-small. Even in the case where $\mathcal{D}$ has $\kappa$-filtered colimits $\mathcal{D} \to \mathrm{Ind}^\kappa (\mathcal{D})$ is rarely an equivalence.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, I admit I'm confused; I don't think I really understand what $\kappa$-small means - I was guessing $\kappa$-small colimit means a colimit over a category whose objects, morphims,etc form a set of cardinality less than $\kappa$. And $\kappa$-filtered colimit is a morphism $f:K^\righttriangle \to D$ where $K$ is a simplicial set all of whose data can be put in a set of cardinality less than $\kappa$. Zhen please tell me where I am going wrong, and why $\kappa$-filtered diagrams are not neccesarily $\kappa$-small.

Comment: You have not understood the definition of $\kappa$-filtered (quasi)categories. If you are not familiar with the ordinary notion, look at that first before looking at the $(\infty, 1)$-version.

Comment: Ok, I see. if $J$ is a $\kappa$-filtered set, it can have cardinality much greater than $\kappa$, so it is not $\kappa$-small. Thanks.